# returning an nsmutuableArray as a pointer that is an mutuablecopy

Tags: objective-c

I dont want to return `manch` because if i `autorelease`  before i  return it ,it becomes invalid to others. so i was thinking of this :

```
 classA
-(NSMutableArray*)set:(NSMutableArray*)data
    {
        manch=  [[data mutableCopy]autorelease]  ;
        int count=2*[data count]; //to not enter infinity loop

        for(int k=0;k< count;k=k+2)
        {
            if(k==count-1)
                [manch addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:![[manch objectAtIndex:k] integerValue] ] ];
        }

        data=[manch mutuableCopy];
        return data;
    }
```

My goal is to create a class that gets an `NSMutuableArray`  do some calculations, than return it, and **NOT TO BE DEPEND** on this class anymore .

**EDIT :**

As people here ask.
in another classB(the user of the method above), i have in the interface :

```
NSMutuableArray *data ;
```

and on the .m file init method i have

```
data=[[NSMutuableArray alloc]init];
```

to use the function from my question, i do :

```
mIns=[[classA alloc]init];
data= [mIns set:[self decimalToBinary:autoWord]];
```

than i loose `data` later.

Comment: I think you don't have a clear understanding of how autoreleasing works. Returning an autoreleased object from a function is fine. The receiver (caller) will have to retain it to keep it.

Comment: Please post actual code; there's no way this works as shown (typos etc). (And, yes, returning an autoreleased object is fine, and actually what you _should_ do in this case.)

Comment: And by the way, did you consider switching to [Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)?

Comment: thank you all. i didnt wanted to use ARC ,because i have to change it all now. but i will try, as regarding to the question , the user that gets this argument, is an NSMutuableArray from another class, that has being allocated in his own class. is that enough ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont want to return manch because if i autorelease before i return it ,it becomes invalid to others. so i was thinking of this:

This is an incorrect statement, you can return an autoreleased object, that's a sane thing to do. It's worth noting that you should design your method names correctly to inform the user what sort of object is returned. Any method whose name begins with  `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy` will return a retained object. ([Source](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH))

In your case, your method name is `set:`, which informs the user of this method that it will return a non retained object (almost always an `autoreleased` object). This is because it isn't prefixed with any of those words mentioned above.

In that case, the issue  you have is with the user of the method; they are not retaining a reference to the object being returned. As such, the user of the method should use it as so:

```
@interface ClassName () {
    NSMutableArray* m_ivarArray;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* propertyArray;
@end

NSMutableArray* data = ...;

// If using a property with retain, setting via "self." will retain it for you
self.propertyArray = [self set:data];

// If using an ivar (which doesn't do the retain for you)
m_ivarArray = [[self set:data] retain];
```

You can avoid these issues by using Automatic Reference Counting (ARC, [More Information](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html)), which will handle this sort of memory management for you. **It is still important that you use the correct naming conventions, as ARC will judge how to manage your memory based on this (in certain situations)**

**Update:** After seeing your update, I can see the problem.

```
data=[[NSMutuableArray alloc]init];
```

This is creating a new instance of `NSMutableArray`, one which is correctly retained (due to what I mentioned before).

```
data= [mIns set:[self decimalToBinary:autoWord]];
```

This is replacing the object held in `data` with a new NSMutableArray, one that is autoreleased. The previous instance you created has been lost, and you've replaced it with another one. This new instance **has not** been retained, and as such, will be released unexpectedly.

To fix, you need to use this instead:

```
NSMutableArray* data = [[mIns set:[self decimalToBinary:autoWord]] retain];
```

You don't need to alloc/init a variable if it will be populated by some other object later on. I strongly suggest brushing up on how this all works, [this might be a good start](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW1).

Comment: thanks a lot for your good answer. the user of the returned value is an NSMutuableArray, in another class, and is allocated first. is this enough ? or i have to retain the value that the user gets from this array ?

Comment: I don't get what you mean, can you provide code which shows what's going on? Please add it to your question, and let me know when you have.

Comment: thank you so much !! your are kind :) so i should not allocate data ? because than i will loose it if send it to another class again no ?

Comment: i have tried something else , instead of copy data, i just work on data and return it. is that ok ??

Comment: I suggest keeping `[[data mutableCopy]autorelease]`, and work with `manch`. The reason being is that the `data` being passed in is a pointer; it's the exact same object the user passed in. If you modify it, it'll change the object the user provided, which might not be what they expect. Instead, you give them a new copy which has been modified, meaning they have their original, and the returned one too.

Comment: "so i should not allocate data", not in this case no, all you needed was a variable to hold the result of the method. `NSMutableArray* variable; variable = ...` is all you need in this case, allocating a new object is overkill (and had the potential to cause more memory leaks)!